# Add feched json data with Ajax to D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, d3.js

Can someone please tell me how can I add fetched json data with Ajax to D3?
I implemented this example https://github.com/samehelhakim/D3-saChart---Bilevel-Partition to my project and just want to populate the radial with my data. Below is a screen-shot with the actual bilevel radial layout:
[image]

The problem is that I must get json from a dinamically url, below is a screen-shot my json data from url:

[image]

And here is the cURL response, if this helps:
`curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/files/3/domains' -H 'Host: 127.0.0.1:5000' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5000/file/3' -H 'Cookie: session=.eJw9kM2KwkAQhF9lmbOHdZJcAh6ESUKE7mCYGLovwq5RMz-7EBXjiO--g4c9VhV8VNVT7I_TcDmL_DrdhoXYjweRP8XHl8gFVEWgYJNG2ZTNNo1asqIM-tI1-mxIl4ZVa8GjJ1PM3LcewsaR75JGnxIKhxHNKcNqN0LfBdbt2Oj6jsFKroro04yylmzYYXCOTRezdQK-9NSXBtXGouyWGLoUjHOk6wfrLmPPvtHOki5iL2dB0kq8FuL7Mh331187_PxPoB4-IdADKgpc7UxEzaDqOU65o4YE-50D3To0bUQWS1ZbievVG3e7DNP7DrEUrz_1nGGI.CXkyKA.wxR75Mly8-Ohvld90-z4CuIenzg' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
{"data": [{"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "11.client-channel.google.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "clients4.google.com"}, {"count": 2, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "likeabosh.hipchat.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "609.talkgadget.google.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "12.client-channel.google.com"}, {"count": 9, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "smetrics.allstate.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "calendar.google.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_id": 3, "name": "ps499ee8d0.pubnub.com"}, {"count": 1, "disabled": 0, "file_i`

This is how I managed to fetch data from url using jQuery Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '{{ url_for("diffs.api_domains", file_id=file.id) }}',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
})
```

You can see the code of the d3 layout here: https://github.com/samehelhakim/D3-saChart---Bilevel-Partition/blob/master/index.html . There is a part with `d3.json("expanses.json", function(error, root) {` and I'm thinking that I must insert my fetched data there.

Please let me know if you need another information on this question, I hope that I explained this correctly.

Comment: Just add the data into the chart in a $.ajax `done` callback function

Comment: @reptilicus can you be more explicit on this, please? Some code would really help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use `d3.json` to go get the data, then just use it to populate the chart whatever way you need to. For instance:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '{{ url_for("diffs.api_domains", file_id=file.id) }}',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (resp) {
   // Transform data as you need it and do all the d3 layout in here
   d3.selectAll('.wedge')
      .data(resp)
      .enter().append(YADA)
});
```

Comment: Nope, I can't use this because the url address is dynamic and that's why I get it with jquery ajax. I specified this in the post.

Comment: What does `.append(YADA)` do?